# How to position UISearchBar scope buttons (UISegmentedControl) above the search bar?

Tags: ios

I am building a table view that provides two lists of data. The design calls for a UISegmentedControl at the top of the table. Being able to search the table should be considered an optional feature (not dependent upon switching between the two lists).

I know that UISearchBar comes with the ability to specify scope buttons, but they appear below the search bar (and are more intended for filtering a search).

How can I position these buttons above the search bar?

Comment: How about you build two arrays with you data. use SegmentedControl to reload data from two different array when switch to different part ?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm planning to do. I'm just trying to figure out how to position the elements correctly on the screen.

Comment: You mean how to handle data on the screen or those views layout? So that I can give you some thought on the answer area.

Comment: The views. Displaying a UISegmentedControl on the screen above the search bar (but below the navigation bar) on a table view.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how the other good app do the layout thing.

1. You can layout it normally. 
   At first you create a UISegmentedControl and UITableView, add them to UIView.

Then UISegmentedControl has method, which can be triggered when you tap on different part, in this method, you call `[myTableView reloadData];` to change the datasource.

[image: Normal layout]

2. Or you can layout your UISegmentedControl in the center of the navigation bar. And layout your table on the view below this.

[image]

- after deciding the main layout, you better make your UISegmentedControl beautiful and elegant. Here's a popular customed UISegmentedControl, that has many style to choose. https://github.com/nealyoung/NYSegmentedControl

[image]

Comment: How can I write the code to achieve the "normal" way in the first option?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand...in the table view controller, in viewDidLoad do I call [self.view.addSubview mySegmentedControlInstance]? Or do I do something else?

Comment: do not use tableviecontroller, use tableview, so that you can add it and uisegmentedcontrol into a normal viewcontroller.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could do that. So you still implement all the table view delegate methods on the normal view controller, correct? How would you write the code to calculate the heights and position everything?

Comment: @Andrew It's out of this topic. This topic is solved, mark it. I'm sorry, you'regonnapost another question. It's a principle of This site.

Comment: How is it off topic? My question is entirely about how to position these views. My question has always been "how to position [the buttons] above the search bar?" I'm not using interface builder. I need to know how to lay out these views programmatically.